# gsoap linux c++ / struct failure delivery

Tags: c++, linux, gsoap

**char** or **int, return value** is passed well.

But **struct** is passed to fail.

server:

```
soapcpp2 -2 -SLix ...
```

client:

```
wsdl2h -f -s -o ... ...
soapcpp2 -i -C ...
```

and

```
struct{
  char * value;
}USER_ITEM
```

server:

```
int Service::GetValue(struct USER_ITEM * item)
{
  item->value = new char[100];
  item->value = "example";
}
```

client:

```
....
ns2__useritemresponse user;
proxy.Getvalue(user)
user.user_item->value  // user.user_item address is null;
....
```

The windows are good. But not on Linux c++.

Are in the same format as above.

Do I need a separate set of options?

Please help if you suspect parts.

Sorry, I did not speak English well.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you compile with -Wall and -Werror do you get any warnings? Is the method `GetValue` or `Getvalue` and what does its declaration look like in the proxy base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot copy a char pointer by using the assignment operator, this is not an std::string:

```
item->value = new char[100];
strcpy(item->value, "example");
```

Comment: Thank you for answers.
But it is not a problem. 
server:
`cout << item-> value << endl; // Output is fine.`
but
server:
`user.user_item // null`  and
`user.user_item-> value // not found`

Comment: Your code seems fishy. Shouldn't it read `proxy.Getvalue(user.user_item);`? Please post your *real* code. The one that compiles.